# Destroy defined key with define function

Tags: php, unset

How I can destroy an const? I tried unset( KEY ), but not work.

```
<?php
define('KEY', 'value');
echo KEY; //output value
unset( KEY ); //no work
?>
```

Comment: The whole point of a constant is that it is immutable after it has been defined. Since you cannot change its value, there is little point to being able to unset it.

Answer (score 9):

Constants created with `define()` can't be undefined once created.

Answer (score 4):

The closest you can get to unsetting a constant is use of the RunKit extension. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.runkit-constant-remove.php

Answer (score 0):

You can't destroy a constant or alter its value during run time.

Your best option is to use a variable.

```
$key = "value";

echo $key;

unset($key);
```

Not to mention; If you could, it would be extremely bad practice :P

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible. If you could unset a constant then it wouldn't be very constant!

If you really need to delete this constant you probably need to use a variable.

Comment: stop assuming what we need to do. There are more people, works, and function asked of programmers than you can think of.

Answer (score 0):

You can't destroy or unset a Constant in PHP and it's value can't change along de Script.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
runkit_constant_remove ( 'KEY' );
```

http://php.net/manual/es/function.runkit-constant-remove.php